# Looking for Matlab to F#/C# Script Convertor

Tags: c#, matlab, f#

I have a bunch of <5 matlab scripts. Is there a tool that can spit out F# or c# equivalent from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rajiv I'm not aware of any script converter but you can compile your Matlab code and then call it from .NET.  Here's two links.  Hope this helps.
[Net Builder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/) and an old project on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/matlabeng.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked
[F# Math Tools](http://www.codeplex.com/fsmathtools) ?